# perl6 How to do something at BEGIN and END of piped $*IN?

Tags: input, raku

In awk, there are special patterns BEGIN and END that allow you to do something before and after the inputs are read. What is the equivalent functions in perl6? For instance:

```
cat someFile | perl6 -ne '{do something before reading input} 
                          {do something else with input}
                          {do something last after all inputs read}'
```

Thanks!

lisprog

Comment: See also documentation chapter [Program Execution Phasers](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers#Program_Execution_Phasers)

Answer (score 3):

```
END say 'end';
say 'middle';
BEGIN say 'begin';
```

displays:

```
begin
middle
end
```

See [Phasers](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers).

Comment: Please note that this could be considered a stopgap measure: the normal FIRST / LAST / NEXT phasers *should* work, but don't at the moment:  https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=129093

Comment: Thank you raiph !! I have not paid much attention to the Phasers section; I guess every bit of knowledge is valuable. I will read more on Phasers.